# How to change helm's highlight color

Tags: helm, colors

I'm using `Monokai` theme. When I start `helm`, the current selected line are highlighted in gray. It's not easy to spot,especially with the title information in blue. [image: Helm in Monokai theme]

How can I change this gray highlight, say, in purple?

Comment: Place the cursor on the area you want to change and type `C-u C-x =` and see what faces are present.  Then you can use `M-x customize-face` to set color under most circumstances; however, there are a few exceptions to the rule.  Sometimes, more than one face will be present at the same location and this is why I recommend seeing what is there before just changing what seems like the most likely choice.

Comment: @lawlist `M-x customize-face` will actually offer you the faces under point as a default. Not that there's anything wrong with checking `C-x =`. :-)

Comment: @Malabarba -- thank you, I wasn't aware it defaults to all faces present at point.

Comment: But when you are in the helm-mini buffer, you can't actually check for the fonts in selection, because it's an active buffer, so you can't type anything. Any solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name of the face helm uses to highlight the selected item is `helm-selection`.  You can change just the background color of any face with `set-background-color`: `(set-background-color 'helm-selection "purple")`.  You can also use`set-face-attribute` like this:

```
(set-face-attribute 'helm-selection nil 
                    :background "purple"
                    :foreground "black")
```

if you also want to set other attributes at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask why it works well in my `init.el` file; while doesn't work in another file loaded in? I put these code in `helm-c.el` and `(load "~/.emacs.d/config/helm-c.el")`. It doesn't work.

Comment: You can use `helm-colors` to search for available faces of a package. For example, if you want to search for all Helm's faces, simply type "helm-" in the prompt of `helm-colors`.